# Can't use float value from dimen file by databinding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.6

in my strings.xml

```
<string name="discount_bonuses_and_ration_lei_placeholder">%1$d B x %2$.2f Lei</string>
```

in my xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />


        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.myprroject.api.model.Invoice" />
    </data>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/discountBonusesTextView"
        style="@style/order_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{@string/discount_bonuses_and_ration_lei_placeholder(item.bonuse, 0.1)}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/discountLabelTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/discountLabelTextView" />

</layout>
```

it's work fine. Nice.

Now I want to replace hardcoded value **0.1** by value from `dimen` file.
So in `values/dimen.xml`

```
<item name="ratio_bonus" format="float" type="dimen">0.1</item>
```

And I write method that get float value from dimen file.

```
  public static float getFloatValueFromDimen(Context context, int dimenKey) {
        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
        context.getResources().getValue(dimenKey, typedValue, true);
        float dimenfloatValue = typedValue.getFloat();
        return dimenfloatValue;
    }
```

Now I want to use this method in xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="com.myproject.util..AndroidUtil" />


        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.myprroject.api.model.Invoice" />
    </data>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/discountBonusesTextView"
        style="@style/order_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{@string/discount_bonuses_and_ration_lei_placeholder(item.bonuse, AndroidUtil.getFloatValueFromDimen(context, @dimen/ratio_bonus))}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/discountLabelTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/discountLabelTextView" />
</layout>
```

But now I get compile error

```
import com.myproject.databinding.ConfirmationActivityBindingImpl;
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ConfirmationActivityBindingImpl
location: package com.myprojectt.databinding
```

`ConfirmationActivity` is activity that use my xml with databinding

Answer (score 1):

**Problem - 1:** You didn't declare `context` in your `xml`, hence data binding shows error and can't create `ConfirmationActivityBindingImpl`

**Solution:** Create variable name `context` with type `android.content.Context`

```
<variable
    name="context"
    type="android.content.Context" />
```

And *initialize* `context` from your `activity`.

Now it successfully create `ConfirmationActivityBindingImpl` and it looks like:

```
....

androidx.databinding.adapters.TextViewBindingAdapter
        .setText(this.discountBonusesTextView, 
                discountBonusesTextView.getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.discount_bonuses_and_ration_lei_placeholder, 100, 
                                discountBonusesTextView.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.ratio_bonus)));

....
```

**Problem - 2:** Then it cause **Resources$NotFoundException** due to `float` type dimension.

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>   **#0x7f060163** type **#0x4** is not valid at android.content.res.Resources.getDimension

If we look inside `getDimension`, There is a type check and `throw` exception if not `TYPE_DIMENSION`

```
if (value.type == TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION) {
    return TypedValue.complexToDimension(value.data, impl.getDisplayMetrics());
}

throw new NotFoundException("Resource ID #0x" + Integer.toHexString(id)
                + " type #0x" + Integer.toHexString(value.type) + " is not valid");
```

**Solution:** We have to pass **Resource Id** instead of **Resource Value**. To do that

- `import` **R.java** inside your `xml`

```
<import type="com.myproject.databinding.R"/>
```

- And then pass resource id like `R.dimen.ratio_bonus`

```
AndroidUtil.getFloatValueFromDimen(context, R.dimen.ratio_bonus)
```

Now it will handle by your `getFloatValueFromDimen` instead of system `getDimension` and everything works fine.

Comment: @a-subscriber, Isn't it help? If so, then please accept the answer